# AWS Cognito and Android example - {"AppCognitoWebDomain":"invalid"}

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Learning Cognito using the Android sample. As far as I can tell I have followed the example on the read me page [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo) except for one thing... There is a section that I do not understand:

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:host="YOUR_REDIRECT_URI_AUTHORITY"android:scheme="YOUR_REDIRECT_SCHEME"/>
</intent-filter>
```

What is the line:

> android:host="YOUR_REDIRECT_URI_AUTHORITY"android:scheme="YOUR_REDIRECT_SCHEME"

The error I am getting in Android Studio is:

> 11-23 21:48:52.860
>   12915-12915/com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                   Process: com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo, PID: 12915
>                                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo/com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo.MainActivity}:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthInvalidParameterException:
>   validation failed
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                                    Caused by:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthInvalidParameterException:
>   validation failed
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.Auth$Builder.validateCognitoAuthParameters(Auth.java:341)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.Auth$Builder.build(Auth.java:288)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo.MainActivity.initCognito(MainActivity.java:121)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                                                    Caused by:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthInvalidParameterException:
>   {"AppCognitoWebDomain":"invalid"}
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.Auth$Builder.validateCognitoAuthParameters(Auth.java:338)
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.Auth$Builder.build(Auth.java:288) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo.MainActivity.initCognito(MainActivity.java:121) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.amazonaws.cognito.android.samples.authdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Answer (score 0):

The host & scheme in intent filter data specify the Cognito app client's redirect URI. For details about data, see [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html). As for what do you configure in your app, see [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/492f1bcccbc836c62cad07051264745bf7dcfd88/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L28) example. So, if you use this example as your data then you would need to set your redirect_uri in Cognito Userpool console as `demoapp://www.loginactivity.com/mainactivity`. As for webdomain, you need to setup your Userpool domain in [strings.xml](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml).